# Single Sign on Asp.net mvc and wcf cross domain separate environments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, cross-domain, single-sign-on

I am currently working on a requirement for the client. Let me brief the scenario

Web Application: Asp.net mvc 5.0 -- deployed on Prod in a web farm environment (BL, Infrastructure and EF DataAccess Layer deployed on these boxes).

Wcf Services - Wcf 4.0 -- deployed on a separate machine

There is a common BL.Services and BL.DataAccess(Entity framework & Sql Server) that is shared between the Wcf and MVC application.

The Wcf hooks into the BL.Services using a Service Facade that acts an interface between the wcf and BL.Services.

Since the authentication flow has to be handshaked across two different boxes or rather two different domains the best solution I could come up with was to build a custom authentication mechanism using single sign on.

For the Single Sign On I am going to create a gateway interface using web services and custom simple membership provider which would encrypt and decrypt the auth cookie. In the mvc app I am using forms authentication again just to pass the cookie across the application urls and I am also passing the same auth cookie to the wcf service using Soap headers when calling the wcf service methods in the business logic.

Questions:-
1.  How can I map the return call between the mvc app and wcf incase say suppose the user is authenticated user on the web box but is not a valid user on the wcf box. Where do I implement the redirect mechanism and do I redirect him back to page from where the call was made (displaying a friendly message)or back to the login page.

2. Is there a way to authenticate the user when the authentication token passes from mvc to wcf through the soap header but before it can execute any business logic method calls on the wcf box(something like a module or a handler).
3. Please guide as to whether I am taking the right track for the above scenario or are there any other ways and means to achieve this.